# Gridview databind takes 20 seconds to load 140 records in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am having issues in displaying the gridview in ASP.Net application. This loads slowly and almost takes 20 seconds to load 140 records. This becomes really slow when using IE browser.

I have a modal popup extender in one of the columns and it looks like it is loading that control every time the grid refreshes and for all rows.

Right now I am doing paging alongwith an option to view all records. Users here wanted to view
all records most of the time. So I need to improve the speed of loading the gridview. Please let me know if there is any other way of using modal popup window other than extender from AJAX.

I am using modal popup window to allow the user to enter some comments related to that particular row.

Thanks in advance
Anil

Answer (score 0):

You must find a way to use only one ModalPopupExtender, not one for each row. Id does render all the controls in the modalpopup'content for each row, it's normal that you page loading is slow!

One way of doing this is to put an update panel inside the ModalPopup, initialize it's contents in the RowCommand event of the gridview (you could store the row/database id in a session variable or HiddenField at this point) and show the pop-up from code behind ([You may need to use a invisible target button](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2008/09/02/controlling-a-ajax-control-modalpopupextender-from-code-behind.aspx))