# Where best to place modal popup in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a GridView which may contain 10's and 100's of rows, on each row is an Edit link that will present the user with a modal popup to allow them to edit some details.

There seem to be 2 approaches:

- Place a modal popup in each row (simplifies population of existing values)
- Have 1 modal popup defined outside of the table and populate using JS and/or AJAX

The 2nd option seems to be the most efficient, but is there a preferred/recommended option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 2nd option is largely better, if you dont do this, you will have a hidden pop-up for each row, which will cause a bloated slow page.

[Here what happen if you use option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164267/gridview-databind-takes-20-seconds-to-load-140-records-in-asp-net/7175788#7175788)

Answer (score 1):

2nd option seems to be the best.